# ZFC : If $I$ is a set, and $A_i$ is a set for every $i$, is $A = \{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ necessarily a set?

Tags: set-theory

I just started to look into the **ZFC** axioms, and I'm not sure what is the answer to the following question:

If $I$ is a set, and $A_i$ is a set for every $i$, is $A = \{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ necessarily a set?

It can be proved very easily for a finite $I$ using induction, but I'm not sure what happens if $I$ is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you mean exactly.

If we work internally to the universe, and you have a first-order definition for $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, then yes. This is a set. Namely, it is the range of the function $i\mapsto A_i$, and if it is definable -- in a very *very* broad sense of the word, then it will be a set by the axiom of replacement.

If you work externally to a model $M$ satisfying $\sf ZFC$. If $M$ happened to be countable, then there will be a bijection between $M$ and $\Bbb N^M$. So $M=\{m_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N^M}$ will not be a set in $M$. Because despite being definable in the meta-theory, it wasn't definable internally to $M$.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was really the first case

Comment: I guessed so; but the second case deserves mentioning, since it may come up if you ever study anything related to set theory or foundations of mathematics.